# Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManagerServerErrorException: Invalid column name:

Tags: asp.net, telerik-grid, dynamic-columns

I am creating dynamic grid in one of my projects. I have added code for grid in `Page_Init` method. Normally I used Bound Column or Template column which is working as expected.
**Here is the code:**

```
protected void Page_Init(object source, System.EventArgs e)
{
     if (Session["colnames"] != null)
     {
         List<CommanIdTitle> CategoryIdTitle = new List<CommanIdTitle>();
         MainSubCategory CateMarks = (MainSubCategory)Session["colnames"];
         GridBoundColumn boundColumn_StudentId;
         boundColumn_StudentId = new GridBoundColumn();
         boundColumn_StudentId.DataField = "StudentId";
         boundColumn_StudentId.HeaderText = "Student Id";
         boundColumn_StudentId.UniqueName = "StudentId";
         boundColumn_StudentId.AllowFiltering = false;
         boundColumn_StudentId.Display = false;
         Grid_CategoryMarks.MasterTableView.Columns.Add(boundColumn_StudentId);

         GridBoundColumn boundColumn_StudentName;
         boundColumn_StudentName = new GridBoundColumn();
         boundColumn_StudentName.DataField = "StudnetName";
         boundColumn_StudentName.HeaderText = "Student Name";
         boundColumn_StudentName.UniqueName = "StudentName";
         boundColumn_StudentName.AllowFiltering = false; 

         Grid_CategoryMarks.MasterTableView.Columns.Add(boundColumn_StudentName);

         GridTemplateColumn templateColumn_AverageFinal;
         templateColumn_AverageFinal = new GridTemplateColumn();
         templateColumn_AverageFinal.ItemTemplate = new MyTemplate2("0");
         templateColumn_AverageFinal.UniqueName = "Average";
         templateColumn_AverageFinal.HeaderText = "Test";
         templateColumn_AverageFinal.HeaderStyle.HorizontalAlign = HorizontalAlign.Center;
         templateColumn_AverageFinal.AllowFiltering = false;
         templateColumn_AverageFinal.ReadOnly = true;
         Grid_CategoryMarks.MasterTableView.Columns.Add(templateColumn_AverageFinal);
    }
}
```

But now the new requirement is to group some of this columns. So I added `GridGroupColumn`.

**Here is new code:**

```
protected void Page_Init(object source, System.EventArgs e)
{
    if (Session["colnames"] != null)
    {
        List<CommanIdTitle> CategoryIdTitle = new List<CommanIdTitle>();
        MainSubCategory CateMarks = (MainSubCategory)Session["colnames"];
        GridBoundColumn boundColumn_StudentId;
        boundColumn_StudentId = new GridBoundColumn();
        boundColumn_StudentId.DataField = "StudentId";
        boundColumn_StudentId.HeaderText = "Student Id";
        boundColumn_StudentId.UniqueName = "StudentId";
        boundColumn_StudentId.AllowFiltering = false;
        boundColumn_StudentId.Display = false;
        Grid_CategoryMarks.MasterTableView.Columns.Add(boundColumn_StudentId);

        GridBoundColumn boundColumn_StudentName;
        boundColumn_StudentName = new GridBoundColumn();
        boundColumn_StudentName.DataField = "StudnetName";
        boundColumn_StudentName.HeaderText = "Student Name";
        boundColumn_StudentName.UniqueName = "StudentName";
        boundColumn_StudentName.AllowFiltering = false;
        Grid_CategoryMarks.MasterTableView.Columns.Add(boundColumn_StudentName);

        /*This code throws error*/
        GridColumnGroup groupHeaderFinal = new GridColumnGroup();
        groupHeaderFinal.Name = "TotalAveragePerTerm";
        groupHeaderFinal.HeaderText = "Total Average Per Term";
        groupHeaderFinal.HeaderStyle.HorizontalAlign = HorizontalAlign.Center;
        Grid_CategoryMarks.MasterTableView.ColumnGroups.Add(groupHeaderFinal);

        GridTemplateColumn templateColumn_AverageFinal;
        templateColumn_AverageFinal = new GridTemplateColumn();
        templateColumn_AverageFinal.ItemTemplate = new MyTemplate2("0");
        templateColumn_AverageFinal.UniqueName = "Average";
        templateColumn_AverageFinal.HeaderText = "";
        templateColumn_AverageFinal.ColumnGroupName = "TotalAveragePerTerm";
        templateColumn_AverageFinal.HeaderStyle.HorizontalAlign = HorizontalAlign.Center;
        templateColumn_AverageFinal.AllowFiltering = false;
        templateColumn_AverageFinal.ReadOnly = true;
        Grid_CategoryMarks.MasterTableView.Columns.Add(templateColumn_AverageFinal);
    }
}
```

When I added this on any postback an error occurred

> Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManagerServerErrorException: Invalid column name:

One solution which I have found is to Set `EnableViewState = False` of grid. But if I do this the `viewstate` is not maintained and grid collapsed and all data is lost.

**Here is my design code**

```
<telerik:RadGrid ID="Grid_CategoryMarks" runat="server" EnableViewState="true"
        AllowFilteringByColumn="True" AllowSorting="True" 
        ShowGroupPanel="false" AutoGenerateColumns="False" PageSize="10" 
        ShowStatusBar="true"  OnNeedDataSource="Grid_CategoryMarks_NeedDataSource"  OnItemDataBound="Grid_CategoryMarks_ItemDataBound"
        ShowFooter="True" FilterItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left">
    <ClientSettings AllowDragToGroup="True">
        <Selecting AllowRowSelect="false" UseClientSelectColumnOnly="true"/>
        <Scrolling AllowScroll="true" UseStaticHeaders="true" SaveScrollPosition="true"/>
    </ClientSettings> 
    <MasterTableView  AutoGenerateColumns="false" >
        <NoRecordsTemplate>
            <asp:Label ID="lbl_rec_msg" runat="server" Text="No record exist"></asp:Label>
        </NoRecordsTemplate>
    </MasterTableView>
</telerik:RadGrid>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have run into similar problem. Problem is that you have defined grid in the design as well as creating it again in `page_init` method.

Remove it from design and try to create from code behind. So each time new instant will be created.